# Why i'm I getting "No routes matched location" when passing a dynamic path variable? (RRD6)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I want to render a dynamic path for one of my components. The component in question is sending the required ID by use of useParams, but when I want to render my component using path="comp/:id" it gives me a white screen and my web console says "No routes matched location /comp". It used to work perfectly before but when migrating to the newest version of RRD it no longer works

Here is an idea of how I am rendering my component

```
<Route
    path="comp/:id" 
    element={
      <React.Fragment>
        {someCondition ?
          <ErrorCatcher key="someKeys" from="Component">
            <Component/>
          </ErrorCatcher>
          :
          <OtherComponent 
            props1="something"
            props2={stuff} 
            etc...
          />
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    } 
/>
```

And in my Component for useParams I do:

```
let { id } = useParams();

const selectedId = useMemo(() => {

    if (id === "something" || !id) {
        return SOMETHING;
    }

    let findIndex = FUNCT_FIND_INDEX(SOMETHING, "id", id);

    if (findIndex !== -1) {
        return SOMETHING[findIndex];
    }
    return OTHER_SOMETHING;

}, [id]);
```

My router and root routes are essentially organized like this all in the App.js file render section

```
<Routes>
   
   <Route path="someComponent/*"/>
   <Route path="anotherComponen/*"/>
   <Route path="comp/:id"/>
   <Route path="/"/>
   
</Routes>
```

In theory this should work, but I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your router and root routes? What and where exactly is this `path="comp/:id"` route rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added this info to the original post

Comment: You are not rendering any route for `path="/comp"` which is what the error is telling you. *Somewhere* the code is navigating to `"/comp"` and there isn't a route for it. Can you edit the code snippets to be more complete code examples so it is clearer what and where they are being rendered and running from? See [mcve].